# difference between /[a-z]/gi and /^[A-Za-z]+$/

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I am validating a text input. When someone enters something in my text input, I first of all remove the spaces from the input and then check for the existence of any character other than A-Z and a-z. When i validate the input using /^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(input_value), i get my desired result however /[a-z]/gi is not working properly. Is there something i am doing wrong here?

Here is what i want:

abCde //accepted

ABCde //accepted

abcDe3 // not accepted

aSc#-er // not accepted

ABCDE_ // not accepted

ABE_Ed // not accepted

Comment: The second example matches if there is a single alphabetic character (case-insensitive) in the input. Your first only matches if every character in the input is alphabetic.

Comment: What do i have to do to make the second one work in the same way as the first one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two examples are quite different.

The first example (`/^[A-Za-z]+$/`) matches only when all characters are in the set `[A-Za-z]`.

The second example (`/[a-z]/gi`) matches if only a single character is alphabetic.

I suspect you want `/^[a-z]+$/i`:

```
/
^      # Matches the start of the string
[a-z]+ # Matches one or more lower case letters
$      # Matches the end of the string
/i     # Case insensitive matching
```

Comment: Example [here](https://regex101.com/r/mDUB8E/1)

Answer (score -1):

Probably the problem is that you do not use the specials chars `^`, `+` and `$`